# Python prints out memory address instead of value

Tags: python

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgjzV.png)

[test data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNtvx.png)

I am trying to get the testReadData() function to print out all the values stored in a csv file. first index is name second index is a number associated with it. For some reason it is only printing out the memory address instead of the actual values. Why is that?

Comment: Why do you *expect it to print anything else*? That *is the value*

Answer (score 1):

You could use dataclass since 3.7, which removes some boilerplate.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class my_class:
    name: str
    number: int
print(my_class('1',1))
```

Comment: also add a note that states —repr— meth is implemented

Answer (score 0):

How could it?  Python doesn't know what the printed value of your custom object should be.  However, you can tell it how to do that:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyData(name={self.name},nbr={self.number})"
```